# need plants to cover and area

Tags: plant-recommendations, ground-cover, tropical, outdoor

"I need hanging plants that can withstand some sun for a garden wall I want to cover (I've looked into Silver Falls Plant). Any other recommendations? Also, plants that can be found in Costa Rica."